# Scala Recursive to Tail Recursive Articulation Point Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scala, recursion, graph, graph-theory

I'm trying to develop an algorithm for finding articulation points within a graph. I'm using the GraphX library from Spark which has a lot of helpful algorithms such as PageRank and connected components, but to my knowledge there is nothing for finding cut edges, or articulation points.

I found [an algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/) to find articulation points written in Java. I translated the algorithm into Scala as shown below:

```
// A recursive function that find articulation points using DFS
// u --> The vertex to be visited next
// visited[] --> keeps tract of visited vertices
// disc[] --> Stores discovery times of visited vertices
// parent[] --> Stores parent vertices in DFS tree
// ap[] --> Store articulation points
@tailrec
def APUtil(u: Int, visited: Array[Boolean], disc: Array[Int], low: Array[Int], parent: Array[Int], ap: Array[Boolean]): Unit = {
  var children = 0;
  visited(u) = true;
  time += 1;
  disc(u) = time;
  low(u) = time;
  val vertexId = graph.vertices.zipWithIndex.map {
    case(k,v) => (v,k)
  }.lookup(u).toMap.keys.iterator.next().toInt;
  val direction: EdgeDirection = EdgeDirection.Out;
  val neighbors = graph.collectNeighborIds(direction).lookup(vertexId)(0);
  for(neighborId <- neighbors) {
    val index =  graph.vertices.zipWithIndex.filter { _._1._1 == neighborId }.collect()(0)._2.toInt;
    if(!visited(index)) {
      children += 1;
      parent(index) = u;
      APUtil(index, visited, disc, low, parent, ap);

      low(u) = math.min(low(u), low(index));

      if(parent(u) == -1  && children > 1) {
        ap(u) = true;
      }

      if(parent(u) != -1 && low(index) >= disc(u)) {
        ap(u) = true;
      }

    } else if (index != parent(u)) {
      low(u) = math.min(low(u), disc(index));
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this on small data, the algorithm works correctly. However, when I use bigger files, Spark throws a StackOverflowError at me. I read up about tail recursion, and I'm having trouble figuring out how I would go about converting this recursive function to a tail recursive one.

Any help appreciated!